# How can I generate a separate NextJS page for each FaunaDB Document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, faunadb

How can I generate a different title on every page within a sub-directory?

My code throws no errors, but unfortunately the `Title` component renders *every* `title-item` on every page that it is supposed to, e.g. every `app.com/title/<title>` renders the *same* view ( a list of titles). I think that `getStaticPaths` is correctly parameterised, but I don't think that `getStaticProps` is.

```
export default function Title({ paper }) {

    // paper is just the entire dataset, and isn't split by id or author etc.

    return (
            <div>
                {paper.map(paper => (
                        <h1>{paper.data.title}</h1>
                ))}
            </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {

    // ideally, results should be split down to e.g. `/api/getPapers/title`, but this didn't work

    const results = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getPapers/`).then(res => res.json());

    return {
        props: {
            paper: results
        }
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const papers = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/getPapers').then(res => res.json());

    const paths = papers.map(paper => {
        return {
            params: {
                authors: paper.data.title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-')
            }
        }
    })

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

This is the `getPapers` API function.

```
const faunadb = require("faunadb");

// your secret hash
const secret = process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET_KEY;
const q = faunadb.query;
const client = new faunadb.Client({ secret });

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dbs = await client.query(
      q.Map(
        // iterate each item in result
        q.Paginate(
          // make paginatable
          q.Match(
            // query index
            q.Index("all_research_papers") // specify source
          )
        ),
        (ref) => q.Get(ref) // lookup each result by its reference
      )
    );
    // ok
    res.status(200).json(dbs.data);
  } catch (e) {
    // something went wrong
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you created an API route to retrieve a single paper by title from FaunaDB? I guess that's what you need in this case. Also, you shouldn't be fetching data from internal API routes in `getStaticProps`, just use the logic directly.

Comment: My API route generates all documents in one batch. Is there any documented example of fetching a document by parameter (i.e. a paper by title)?

Comment: Can you share you `getPapers` API function?  `papers` might be a couple of things depending on how you return the result from Fauna.

Comment: @ptpaterson, I've included the API function above.

Comment: @WΔ_, I've updated the answer based on the API function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempts to render a separate page for each document were missing a *dynamic* API call. I was simply hoping to render dynamic pages with a *single* (batched-document) API call.

Here is a typical dynamic API route called `[index.js]`:

```
const faunadb = require('faunadb')

// your secret hash
const secret = process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET_KEY
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({ secret })

export default async (req, res) => {
  const {
    query: { index },
  } = req;

  try {
    const papers = await client.query(
      q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection('<name of the collection>'), index))
    );
    res.status(200).json(papers.data);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
};
```

Once your data is being retrieved dynamically, you can set up a dynamic *page* route, e.g. `[id].js`, that fetches the data using [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app).

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/getPapers/${id}`, fetcher);
```

This is an example fetcher function:

```
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());
```

In my case, I could then retrieve any given field using the call `{data.<field>}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `authors` in your Path object.  You will need to make sure that your page file is named with `authors` included.  For example:

```
app_directory
|- pages
  |- home.js
  |- title
    |- [authors].js
```

Perhaps where you say `authors` in your `params` object, you do mean `title`.  In which case, rename the `params` object and page filename.

```js
    const paths = papers.map(paper => {
        return {
            params: {
                title: paper.data.title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-')
            }
        }
    })
```

```
app_directory
|- pages
  |- home.js
  |- title
    |- [title].js
```

Here are the docs for `getStaticPaths()`. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

EDIT:

Since your API function returns the Page from your query, the shape of the result will likely be

```js
{
  before: [/* before cursor */],
  after: [/* after cursor */],
  data: [
    { /* paper Document */ },
    { /* paper Document */ },
    { /* paper Document */ },
  ]
}
```

In which case, your code will need to map over `papers.data` not on `papers` itself.

```js
    const paths = papers.data // select the data
      .map(paper => {
        return {
            params: {
                title: paper.data.title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-')
            }
        }
    })
```